# Get a warning when replying email from a different identity in Thunderbird?

Tags: email, thunderbird

I use Thunderbird 31.2.0 and I need to get warning when replying email from a different identity.

For example, I got a message from `someone@gmail.com` to `myemail_1@gmail.com`:

```
From : someone@gmail.com
Subject : something
To : myemail_1@gmail.com
```

When I reply with myemail_2@gmail.com:

```
From : myemail_2@gmail.com
Subject : something
To : someone@gmail.com
```

How to make Thunderbird warn me for replying from an email which doesn't match the one I received ?

Comment: Excellent question.  Looking forward to an answer.

Comment: If it already displays the warning.  I am not sure I understand the question.

Comment: @Ramhound - that's the problem, it doesn't display a warning.  If you use Thunderbird to consolidate email from various accounts and reply to a message, it doesn't use the sent-to email address as the basis for the return address on the reply.  It is definitely a pain in the butt and it is too easy to send out replies with the wrong return address.

Answer (score 0):

Use an extension for that.

If you're interested only in sending from the right address you can use [Identity Chooser](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/thunderbird/addon/identity-chooser/).

Or you can look at [different solutions](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/thunderbird/search/?q=identity&appver=31.0), maybe one of them fits your needs better. Some of them even give warnings in some cases (like [Correct Identity](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/thunderbird/addon/correct-identity)), but not in necessarily in the case you described, and you may also need to do some manual settings.